# Export Canvas After a for loop shows up blank

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have an issue with Drawing to the Canvas. I can see that the images are being draw but it looks like its doing so async. Im kinda a newbie when it comes to canvas and drawing so ive been following some tutorials.

Right now i'm using a for loop to draw the images at specific locations to create a texture page hence the for loop to get the percise x and y locations and later to be exported/downloaded. The images all show up but after its done, the dataurl shows up as blank. I mostly just console.log the info to see if the image was properly converted.

Here is how my code looks

```
function createImage(ctx,img,x,y){  
    var image = new Image(); 
    image.src = img;
    image.onload = function(){ 
    ctx.drawImage(image,x,y);
    } 
}



  for(var n = 0 ; n <=blocks.length-1 ; n++) 
  {
  var block = blocks[n];

if (block.fit) 
{ 
    var c = document.getElementById("export");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    createImage(ctx,'assets/'+blocks[n].img,block.fit.x, block.fit.y); 
   
}
else
{
    console.log("Block :"+n+" Did Not Fit To Square ");
}

   if (n == blocks.length-1)
   {
      download();
    }
  }

    function download(){
   var mycanvas = document.getElementById("export"); //get your canvas
    var image  = mycanvas.toDataURL("image/png"); 
    console.log(image) //Test to see if it was successful
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```js
const mycanvas = document.getElementById("export");
const ctx = mycanvas.getContext('2d');

const testimg = 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/2cab66446c8718f41ad98ed7fbdc8d05?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1';
const blocks = [{
    img: testimg,
    fit: {
      x: 50,
      y: 50
    }
  },
  {
    img: testimg,
    fit: {
      x: 100,
      y: 100
    }
  }
];

createImage(testimg, 0, 0, drawBlocks);
//drawBlocks();
//download();

function createImage(img, x, y, f) {
  var image = new Image();
  image.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
  image.src = img;
  image.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(image, x, y);

    if (f) {
      f();
    }
  }
}

function drawBlocks() {
  for (var n = 0; n <= blocks.length - 1; n++) {
    var block = blocks[n];

    if (block.fit) {
      //TODO: change back to: 'assets/' + blocks[n].img
      createImage(blocks[n].img, block.fit.x, block.fit.y, ((n == blocks.length - 1) ? (download) : (null)));

    } else {
      console.log("Block :" + n + " Did Not Fit To Square ");

      if (n == blocks.length - 1) {
        download();
      }
    }
  }
}

function download() {
  var image = mycanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  console.log(image) //Test to see if it was successful
}
```

```html
<canvas id="export" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

It looks like the context was being changed each time a block was drawn, rather than simply referring to the same context. Also, `createImage` kept calling itself in an infinite loop - separating drawing the blocks into its own function fixes that. Finally, the `image.onload` function happens after the `createImage` function returns, so anything that must happen after that cannot be coded synchronously.

Comment: I looked at the dataurl and it doesn't seem to work when trying to convert back to png.  also  how come you but the fit:{w,h} in the section? Im going off of this For the fit to rectangle. https://github.com/jakesgordon/bin-packing/blob/master/js/packer.js i though tthat the purpose of fit: was to try to return if the blocks fit to the rectangle boundary

Comment: Ok, I've updated the answer to solve that issue too, but I had to significantly change the original code. As the question didn't include what the definition of a `block` was, I made an educated guess based on what the code is doing, just to be able to test it.

Comment: Thanks for helping out, I had to change a few things to get it to work. Sorry for not properly explaining what blocks did. Basically Blocks is just an array containing the w/h of the sprite to push onto the canvas. The information is passed via json array and initalized with the   "var packer = new Packer(4029, 4029); packer.fit(blocks);" Which i seemed to have left out in my original code. I just used the drawBlocks function instead of the createimage initally since I dont have the raw image info till the ajax returns true. The Array is built via for loop to build the w/h info into "blocks"